# Word for a male with a nice body?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is a common adjective to describe a guy with a nice physique?

Answer (score 17):

Consider **Hunk**, from [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hunk)

> a large, strong, sexually attractive man.
>
> *"a Hollywood hunk"*

synonyms: muscleman, strongman, macho

To use it as an adjective, try *hunky*.

> *"The sexy stars fell out over hunky footballer Lee"*

Answer (score 12):

Well, not an area of the language that I commonly delve into, but for those with a classical bent there's [Adonis](http://www.maicar.com/GML/Adonis.html).

Comment: I like this answer, especially for its classical bent, but my sense of *Adonis* is that it refers to a man who's all-around gorgeous, face included, and doesn't restrict itself to simply "men who have nice bodies or physiques", as hunk/beefcake etc do.

Comment: How's that an adjective?

Comment: @NVZ - Come now -- one can always adjectivize a term somehow.  "Adonis-like", for instance.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, English simply works, just like you ***verbed*** the noun ***adjective***

Answer (score 11):

There is a pitfall here in that some of the available words (of which there are not many specifically for physique) have a connotation of physical attraction of the speaker to the male subject.

Types of body-describing adjectives include :

- relatively objective physical judgement analogous to Body Mass Index. *Chiseled*, *built*, *ripped* essentially state that the person is in the upper percentiles of muscularity.  *Fit* is less specific, but conveys the same judgement for overall physical fitness.  One can imagine these words as a condensed summary of medical and athletic tests, and they say nothing about what the speaker finds attractive or not.
- a relatively distanced social judgement such as *movie-star good looks* or *handsome*.  These describe a presumed typical response of the "average person on the street" to the subject's appearance, or how that appearance fits some presumed norms of beauty.  *Strapping* is one of the very few words in this category that might apply to male physique.
- breathless adjectives like *hunk* (*hunky* even more so), *beefcake*, and in some contexts *Adonis*, that sound like they are drawn from conversations of male homosexuals or teenage girls about men they find attractive.  Using these words can create the impression that the speaker is describing their own attraction to the subject beyond what the general population might see in the same male.

A test for neutrality versus breathless praise might be: would one heterosexual male talking to another plausibly use the term about a third? In the environments I'm familiar with, *studly* passes this test, *hunky* fails it badly, *Adonis* sometimes passes and often fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, the connotation of a given term can be highly dependent on current terminology among various segments of society, and it's hard to predict (without being privy to the segment's lingo) what will have a neutral connotation vs what will have strong off-color sexual implications.

Comment: Solid. However ripped/chiseled refer not so much to muscularity but to low body-fat level won top of that muscularity (with subtle distinctions between the two as some wouldn't call a ripped mass monster chiseled).

Answer (score 8):

Consider,

***studly***

> *Slang.* virilely attractive; muscular and handsome. [1955–60]
>
> stud: *Slang.* a usually young man regarded as attractive and well-built.
> [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/studly)

***hot***

> *Slang.* sexually attractive. [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hot)

Comment: I was thinking about [well-built](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-built) itself. I think it works too.

Answer (score 5):

**Handsome as a Greek god**

Example: *As handsome as a Greek god and as careless of human life, his perfect face is a mask that hides an awesome cruelty*.

Comment: This might look fine, but OP asked for a single word.